# Linking code layout with xml layout file

Tags: android, xml, layout

I created a activity with 9 grey blocks on background using the following code:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    canvas.drawLine(width/3, 0, width/3, height, paint);
    canvas.drawLine((2*width)/3, 0, (2*width)/3, height, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, height/3, width, height/3, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, (2*height/3), width  , (2*height)/3, paint);

    Log.d("game","in draw");

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

     layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setId(1);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    layout.addView(imageView, params);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    Log.d("game","before content view");

    // Show this layout in our activity.
    setContentView(layout);
```

So i have created an layout purely by code.
Now I want to link this layout with an xml file such that any change in that file or in the code will be also seen in the activity.  How to do so.

Comment: `link a layout with an xml file` - a layout **IS** an XML file.  Your question is unclear.  Please edit it to describe exactly **what** you are trying to achieve.  Forget about the **how** for the time being.

Comment: the  title says **Linking code layout with xml layout file**. Its explains enough that I have created an activty whose layout is programmed instead of using another xml file to do so. Now I want to link this with a xml file so that I can use both to change the activity's view.

Comment: So why cant you use setContentView() to inflate the XML?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `linking` those two.

Comment: Looking that you already use `Paint` and `Canvas`, I would recommend you to create a custom `View` instead, so that it will be reusable and support `xml` tag. [Link to official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Comment: You have created a layout programatically, you mean you have created the layout XML in your code?

Comment: By **linking** I meant is there a way to sync them. I have created this view in onCreate() now if I create a layout xml file with transparent background and arrange imageview as I want them to be and then I setContentView() that layout later in the program then will this layout will show on top of the other one or just one of them will appear?

Comment: `setContentView()` will overwrite the layout, thus it will clear the background that you have created by code. On the other hand, I really recommend you to create a custom `View` just to draw that background. With this, you can use `FrameLayout` to stack your background `View` with `ImageView`

Comment: Seems like a good way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can if class extend from Activity,ListActivity,...etc.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }
}
```

You can change or add layout to code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //activity_main is Layout you can change it
```